# (Qt) LineEdit with suggestion delegate that read options from model (not working)

Tags: c++, qt, view, model, delegates

I'm trying to set up a delegate that has a lineedit with suggestions that are read from a model.

So, I tried passing the model that delegate should read the information from, this is not working since after the delgate is constructed, the model that the QCompleter is looking at doesn't not show the external modifications made to recived_model. So it does only work making the right suggestions when the recived_model hasn't changed...

Considering that the delegates is being used to modify the contents of recived_model. I think there should be a way to access the data of the column I want the completer to get suggestions from. I think this could be done using a "for" and the data function to set up a new QStringList that constains only the information from the column that I wanted the completer to use as suggestions. But this show be redone any time other item in the view is accessed. I'm same as start, no idea how to achieve this.

Here is my code... Hope you can help:

```
//header
class myDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    myDelegate(QWidget* parent=0,QSqlTableModel *recived_model, int col_pr);

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget* editor, QModelIndex const& index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget*editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, QModelIndex const& index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& index ) const;

    ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy *model_pr;
    int col_proxy;//Only column from the recived 
                    //model that remains

};
```

and the implementation:

```
//cpp
myDelegate::myDelegate(QWidget* parent,QSqlTableModel *recived_model, int col_pr)
                       : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
    model_pr = new ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy(parent,col_pr);
    model_pr->setSourceModel(recived_model);
    col_proxy = col_pr;
}


QWidget* myDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& index) const
{
    QLineEdit *editor = new QLineEdit(parent);

    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(model_pr);

    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    completer->setCompletionColumn(3);
    completer->setFilterMode(Qt::MatchContains);
    //completer->setMaxVisibleItems()
    completer->setModelSorting(QCompleter::UnsortedModel);

    editor->setCompleter(completer);

    return editor;
}


void myDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, QModelIndex const& index) const
{
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    QString currentText = index.model()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();
    lineEdit->setText(currentText);
}



void myDelegate::setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, QModelIndex const& index) const
{
    QLineEdit *lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    model->setData(index, lineEdit->text(), Qt::EditRole);
}



void myDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor, QStyleOptionViewItem const& option, QModelIndex const& index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

.

.
.
ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy

```
class ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy(QObject* parent=0,int column=0);

    void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* sourceModel);

protected:
    bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,
                const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const;

private slots:
    void clearCache() { cache.clear(); }

private:
    int Column;
    mutable QStringList cache;
};
```

Implementation:

```
#include "modelwithoutduplicatesproxy.h"
#include <QDebug>

ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy::ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy(QObject* parent,int column)
: QSortFilterProxyModel(parent)
{
    Column = column;
    //setDynamicSortFilter(true);
}



bool ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow,
        const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    qDebug() << "filterAcceptsRow!";

    QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow,
                        Column,sourceParent);

    const QString &text = sourceModel()->data(index, Qt::EditRole).toString();


    //qDebug() << "El texto es:" << text << ".\n";

    if (cache.contains(text,Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        return false;
    else
    {
        cache << text;
        qDebug() << "Else: El texto es:" << text << ".\n";
        return true;
    }

}


void ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy::setSourceModel(
        QAbstractItemModel *sourceModel)
{
    connect(sourceModel, SIGNAL(modelReset()),
                this, SLOT(clearCache()));

    QSortFilterProxyModel::setSourceModel(sourceModel);
}
```

There it is the code of the duplicates deleter.

Comment: Your delegate is OK. The problem most probably is in `ModelWithoutDuplicatesProxy`. Show its code.

Comment: @Ezee Definition of the proxy model added

Comment: You implemented `filterAcceptsRow` incorrectly. You must implement it in a way it can be requested with a random index in any order. For example, if to call your method for one index twice, it will return true the first time and false the second time.

Comment: I thought filterAcceptsRow is called only in constructor of the proxy and when data changes.
the situation I contemplated was that two rows can contein the same information and I don't want the lineedit to suggest two times the same.
I don't know why filterAcceptsRow would be called twice on the same index if it hasn't been modified.
The only solution I came up with was to have a cache of all the word I have already accepted (filterAcceptsRow=true).
I'll read the Doc on proxies since I don't understand what I have to do, to make the model work as you say, i mean, without using a the cache@Ezee

Comment: As I said you shouldn't rely on an order of calling `filterAcceptsRow`. My suggestion is to subscribe the proxy to signals from the source model. When source model is changed find all duplicate indexes and then return `false` for them in `filterAcceptsRow`.

Comment: I understand you are suggesting me to set up the proxy so it does find all the duplicates every time the source model is changed. To do this, I would need to access all the data from the source model every time dataChanger is signaled. I don't know how to access all the indexs of a model inside a delegate.
In addition to that, why should I suscribe the proxy to signals of the source model, considering I knew how to do it, isn't in the whole porpouse of using models and proxies that you can use them, without worring about the changes in one another since, in theory, all changes would summited

Comment: from the changed model to all it's proxies and viceversa. That's what I read on qt docs when learning about models.

Comment: You can access model data from proxy using `sourceModel()->data(sourceModel()->index(row, column)))`

Comment: Proxy already subscribed to all model signals, but proxy can do 2 things: 1) sort items 2) filter items where a filter is a function of row data.  If you can make a decision to filter out a row based on row data then there is no any subsciptions, data needed. But you can't. Because to know whether a row is a duplicate or not you need to know other rows values. And that's why you need additional data sources.

Comment: Another way is to sort the source model. In this case it will be enough for you to check that `sourceModel()->data(sourceModel->index(source_row-1,0))` is not equal to current row data.